# Bluebird Promises Join behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

If I execute the following code with Node.js

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.join(
    function A() { console.log("A"); },
    function B() { console.log("B"); }
).done(
    function done() { console.log("done");}
);
```

The console will log

```
B
done
```

However I would expect

```
A
B
done
```

or

```
B
A
done
```

If it set a break point in function A it is never reached. Why is it that it processes B but not A?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Promise.join` takes *promises* as all its arguments but its last one, which is a function.

```
Promise.join(Promise.delay(100), request("http://...com"), function(_, res){
       // 100 ms have passed and the request has returned.
});
```

You're feeding it two functions so it does the following:

- Make a promise over `function A() { ... }` - basically returning a promise over it
- When it's done (immediately) execute the last argument, `function B() {... }` logging it.

See the docs:

> `Promise.join(Promise|Thenable|value promises..., Function handler) -> Promise`
>
> For coordinating multiple concurrent discrete promises. While .all() is good for handling a dynamically sized list of uniform promises, Promise.join is much easier (and more performant) to use when you have a fixed amount of discrete promises that you want to coordinate concurrently, for example:
>
> `var Promise = require("bluebird");`
>
> `var join = Promise.join;`
>
> `join(getPictures(), getComments(), getTweets(),`
>
> `function(pictures, comments, tweets) {`
>
> `console.log("in total: " + pictures.length + comments.length + tweets.length);`
>
> `});`

---

Update:

JSRishe came up with another clever way to solve this sort of pattern [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222439) which looks something like:

```
Promise.delay(100).return(request("http://...com").then(function(res){
    // 100 ms have passed and the request has returned 
});
```

This works because the request already happens before the delay returns since the function is called in the same scope.

Comment: Is there anything `.join()` does that `.all()` can't do?  Or is it just a different syntax?

Comment: @jfriend00 `Promise.join(p1, p2,..., pn, fn)` behaves like `Promise.all([p1, p2, ..., pn]).spread(fn)` except it's slightly faster. This is useful for a fixed number of promises and is nice sugar for using promises as proxies: `var p1 = asyncOp(); var p2 = p1.then(otherOp); var p3 = p2.then(oneMore); Promise.join(p1, p2, p3, function(r1, r2, r3){ ...` . The other advantage it has is better type information in languages like TypeScript since it is easier to statically analyze.