# Set minimum delay on bluebird.js promise resolution

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I want to guarantee a minimum delay on the resolution of a [bluebird.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) promise.

As an example, let's say I'm making a request wrapped in a promise. The behaviour I want is that if the request takes less than 5 seconds, I want to artificially increase the delay of the promise resolution to 5 seconds. If the request were to take more than 5 seconds, I'd want no artificial delay added - so it's a little more complicated than just adding a static delay to every request. All of this should be completely hidden from the consumer of the promise - they should just see the promise being resolved in 5 seconds, or more.

To demonstrate, I've got a simple mock implementation example which hardcodes the mocked request latency at 3 seconds.

My first try went something like this - using a setTimeout to ensure the resolve callback isn't called before 5 seconds have passed.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vu95ac07/)

```
function getTimestamp() {
  return new Date().getTime();   
}

function makeCallWith3SecondLatency(cb) {
  console.log('mocking a call with 3 second latency...');
  var mockResult = 'the result';
  setTimeout(function() { cb(mockResult); }, 3000);
}

function doSomethingAsync(minDelay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var calledAt = getTimestamp();
    makeCallWith3SecondLatency(function(arg) {
      var actualDelay = getTimestamp() - calledAt;
      if(actualDelay < minDelay) {
        var artificialDelay = minDelay - actualDelay;
        console.log('artificially delay another ' + artificialDelay + ' millis');
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(arg); }, artificialDelay);
      } else {
        resolve(arg);
      }
    });
  });
}

function printResult(result) {
  console.log('result: ' + result)   
}

var minDelay = 5000;
doSomethingAsync(minDelay).then(printResult);
```

A lot of boilerplate.

I then discovered through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842500/bluebird-promises-join-behaviour) that I could use the Promise.join function to join the promise wrapping the request with a Promise.delay of the minimum 5 second delay to achieve the same thing:

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s572rg7y/)

```
function makeCallWith3SecondLatency(cb) {
  console.log('mocking a call with 3 second latency...');
  var mockResult = 'the result';
  setTimeout(function() { cb(mockResult); }, 3000);
}

function doSomethingAsync(minDelay) {
  return Promise.join(
                new Promise(function(resolve) { makeCallWith3SecondLatency(resolve); }),
                Promise.delay(minDelay).then(function() { console.log('artificially delaying 5 seconds with Promise.delay') }),
                function(result) { return result; });
}

function printResult(result) {
  console.log('result: ' + result)   
}

var minDelay = 5000;
doSomethingAsync(minDelay).then(printResult);
```

This is cleaner, but still a little more boilerplate than I'd like - I've dug around the [bluebird api reference](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisejoinpromisethenablevalue-promises-function-handler---promise) and can't find a function which does this directly.

My question is simple - **can anybody suggest a cleaner, more declarative way of achieving this behaviour with bluebird than the second example?**

Any suggestions of other promise libraries where the api does offer this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that all you need to do is `Promise.delay(value).return(promise)`:

You can wrap it in a utility function:

```
function stallPromise(promise, delay) {
    return Promise.delay(delay).return(promise);
}

function doSomethingAsync(minDelay) {
    var p = new Promise(makeCallWith3SecondLatency); 

    return stallPromise(p, minDelay);
}

var minDelay = 5000;
doSomethingAsync(minDelay).then(printResult);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s572rg7y/1/

**Note** that one thing about this is that if the promise rejects, the delayed promise will not reject until the five seconds have elapsed. This may be the desired behavior (as @Benjamin Gruenbaum points out in the comments), but if you would prefer for it to reject immediately, two other options are:

With `Promise.join`:

```
function stallPromise(promise, delay) {
    // if you're using underscore/lodash, you can use _.identity for this
    function identity(val) { return val; }

    return Promise.join(promise, Promise.delay(delay), identity);
}
```

Or @Benjamin Gruenbaum's approach with `Promise.all`:

```
function minDelay(promise, delay) {
    Promise.all([promise, Promise.delay(delay)]).get(0);
}
```

Comment: If you're doing Promise.join with identity can't that just be `Promise.all`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What do you have in mind? `Promise.all([promise, Promise.delay(delay)])` will return a promise for an array of two values.

Comment: Oh you're right since `delay` in this case is always bigger or equal to the time we want for it to take for the promise to resolve. Clever.

Comment: That `.return` is a nice idea, but unfortunately has unfavourable behaviour: if `promise` is rejected within the delay, the error will not immediately bubble but be delayed as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! When I looked at `delay(x)` I was somehow thinking it would just add a static x millis onto whatever time it took to resolve p. Of course this is wrong because the actual request inside of p is spun off as soon as p is created, so p might be ready to resolve instantly when it's returned after x millis. I'm still getting into the promises way of thinking, this has been very helpful!

Comment: @davnicwil `Promise.delay(promise, 5000)` and `promise.delay(5000)` _do_ have precisely that behavior (delay `promise` by an additional 5000ms). `Promise.delay(5000).return(promise)` doesn't do that, but it has a nasty bug that Bergi pointed out. I've reverted back to my earlier answer and added a few extra comments.

Comment: @Bergi I think that this is actually better behaviour - if you're throttling an API at a call per 1000ms and the calls reject after 1ms since you passed the limit instead of getting the reject delayed (fixing the throttle problem) you might make more and more requests in succession (retrying) making the problem worse.

Comment: Ok, a really good point by @Bergi, didn't spot that but actually in my particular use case that's ok - probably mixing my terminology but I want a min delay on any resolution of the promise, success or error.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah ok it depends on the use case. However for throttling I would try to separate the result-promise from the wait-promise anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### Your problem

First of all, the promisification of the other 3 second call is irrelevant here, it should not be part of the promise. While I'm flattered you liked my answer with `.join` it is also not a tool I'd actually use here.

First, the API call is just an arbitrary promise returning function.

```
function yourApiCall(){
    // your function that returns a promise AFTER promisificatin
}
```

Actually, we don't really care about it. It might as well just be:

```
var p = ... ; //p is a promise
```

Now we want to make sure at least 3 seconds pass before we resolve p.

```
function minDelay(p, ms){ // stealing name from JLRishe's answer
    return Promise.all([p, Promise.delay(ms)]).get(0);
}
```

Which takes an arbitrary promise and returns a promise that takes at least `ms` milliseconds to resolve.

```
minDelay(p, 300).then(function(el){
   // el is minDelay's return value and at least 300 ms have passed
});
```

You can also put it on Bluebird's prototype (if you're writing a library be sure to get your own isolated copy first):

```
Promise.prototype.minDelay = function minDelay(ms){
    // note that unlike the example above this will delay 
    // on rejections too 
    return Promise.delay(ms).return(this);
}
```

Which would let you declaratively do:

```
p.minDelay(300).then(function(res){
   // access result
});
```

### A more general problem

Often when people ask about this problem what they actually care about is making a function return a result at most every number of milliseconds or make a function act as a *monitor* for how often calls are made. This is to throttle the number of calls that are made to a web service that rate-limits. This should be limited at the *level of the function that returns the promise*. For example:

```
var queue = Promise.resolve();
function throttle(fn, ms){
    var res = queue.then(function(){ // wait for queue
        return fn(); // call the function
    });
    queue = Promise.delay(ms).return(queue); // make the queue wait
    return res; // return the result
}
```

This would let you do:

```
function myApiCall(){
    // returns a promise
}
var api = throttle(myApiCall, 300); // make call at most every 300 ms;

api(); // calls will be sequenced and queued
api(); // calls will be made at most every 300 ms
api(); // just be sure to call this directly, return this to consumers
```

Comment: @JLRishe I switched all the ones but the first one to the same pattern your answer has since it's nicer anyway.

Comment: But did you notice that it does something different?

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, the use of `all` rather than `join` is definitely more appropriate

Comment: @Bergi yes, and I like it much better.

Comment: Hm, I find non-immediate errors (rejections) quite undesirable. At least you should mention the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code to min-delay a Promise:

```js
const sleep = async ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const pMinDelay = async (promise, ms) => {
  const [result] = await Promise.all([promise, sleep(ms)]);

  return result;
};

export default pMinDelay;
```

Import the `pMinDelay` function where you want do delay a Promise.

I hope that helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

Library [spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex) was written specifically to deal with issues like data throttling and load balancing when using promises.

In your case we can use the following example:

```
var spex = require('spex')(Promise);

function source(index, data, delay) {
    var start = Date.now();
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        // request your data here;

        var end = Date.now();
        if (end - start < 5000) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve();
            }, 5000 - end + start);
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    });
}

function dest(index, data, delay) {
    // you can do additional load balancing here,
    // while processing the data;
}

spex.sequence(source, dest)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("DATA:", data);
    });
```

But that's just scratching the surface, because the library lets you implement much more flexible, and advanced (if you want) strategies for dealing with the promise requests.

For your case what might be interesting is parameter `delay` that's passed into both the source and destination functions, so the load balancing can be handled two-ways when needed.

In addition, you can employ method [page](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/code/page.md) with the same load balancing strategy, but processing requests in pages.