# Correctly passing parameters to setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

I am working on a Node.js project, and I am having issues wrapping a `Promise` function with a `setTimeout` function.

My original `Promise` function:

I want to wrap this function in a call to `setTimeout()` but am having trouble passing in the `Promise` object. I need the `Promise` object and the data object available inside the `setTimeout()` function, but when I pass them into `setTimeout()` as parameters i still get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**My code:**

```
return Promise.props(data).then(function (data) {
    data.companies = data.order && data.order.companies;
    if (!data.companies) {
        data.companies = {};
        data.companies[data.company.id] = data.company;
    }

    if (data.order) {
        if (data.order.contactentry) {
            data.order.pointofcontact = data.order.contactentry + ' ' + phone(data.order.contactentryphone);
        } else if (data.order.borrowername) {
            data.order.pointofcontact = data.order.borrowername + ' ' + phone(data.order.borrowerphone);
        } else if (data.order.lockboxcode) {
            data.order.pointofcontact = 'Lockbox ' + data.order.lockboxcode
        }
    }

    if (data.part && data.order && data.part.vendor) {
        var oid = data.order && data.order.id;
        var vid = data.part && data.part.vendor && data.part.vendor.id;
        if (!oid || !vid) {
            var e = new Error('Could not assemble vendor accept url, order id or part vendor id are missing')
            log.error({
                error: e,
                data,
            }, e.message);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    return data;
});
```

The data object is available inside the function when passed in as a parameter, but the `Promise` object is not. 
How can I properly pass in the `Promise` object to make it available inside `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Why do you want to wrap a `Promise` with `setTimeout`?

Comment: you're missing the `new` keyword before `Promise`

Comment: in your "also tried" code, the `data` in `.then` isn't the same as the data passed in to `function(Promise, data)`

Comment: @JosanIracheta - Promise.props doesn't require `new` :p - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html

Comment: @JaromandaX I learn something new everyday :D

Comment: @swalker: I need to delay execution of the Promise function to give the code that populates the passed data object time to finishing executing. Without a delay, the data object isn't populated yet when it is manipulated inside the `Promise` function.

Comment: `How can I properly pass in the Promise object` you are doing it properly - what is Promise outside of the code you posted? why pass it at all if it's just a global as your code seems to suggest

Comment: There is nothing to return to inside `setTimeout`. I suspect you haven't shown all the code and there is a subsequent `then()` that throws that error

Comment: ugh @McWayWeb - you're using a delay to wait for asynchronous code to complete, before using a Promise to return it? seriously? you do realise the promise returned by `return Promise.props` isn't being returned anywhere, right? Somehow I think you seem to think you can make asynchronous code synchronous by using Promises (hint: you can't)

Comment: by the way, your "also tried" code is a correct way to pass arguments to the setTimeout callback - but your overall problem will not be solved using this type of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this inside-out. When you want to incorporate non-promise async code (such as `setTimeout`) into your promise-based code, you should isolate the wrapped non-promise part instead of getting it mixed too deep in the rest of your promise code.

Promise wrapper for `setTimeout`:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
return Promise.props(data)
    .then(function (result) {
      return delay(1000).return(result);
    });
```

Since you appear to be using Bluebird, you can also skip all the `setTimeout` stuff and use the built-in `.delay` method:

```
return Promise.props(data).delay(1000);
```

Note that either of the above will add an *additional* 1 second delay to the time it takes to resolve all of the promises in `data`. If your goal is to just make it so that the minimum total time is 1 second, then you can use my approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222439/set-minimum-delay-on-bluebird-js-promise-resolution):

```
return Promise.delay(1000).return(Promise.props(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about using the arguments/return value of setTimeout, and just make use of `new Promise`

Delaying before Promise.props is called:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    resolve(Promise.props(data));
  }, 1000);
});
```

Or, delaying the result of Promise.props:

```
return Promise.props(data).then(function (data) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Edit: If you're using Bluebird it looks like they have delay operators built in:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/delay.html
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html

Comment: Notice that you should not delay calling `Promise.props` when the promises in `data` had been constructed previously. If one of them got rejected, it would trigger an `unhandledRejection` warning.